# Custom UITableViewCell Button Calling Incorrect Target

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a strange situation that I just can't seem to fix. I have a tableView with 2 sections. Both sections have the same CustomTableViewCell (ShareActivityCustomTableViewCell.swift).

Each cell has a UIButton (custom switch button).

**The Problem**

When a user taps on the custom switch button in section 1, the cell is removed from section one and placed in section 0. This part of the process works fine.

However, as soon as the tableView reloads and the user taps on the same custom switch in section 0 the app crashes because the index is out of range. It would be out of range because when the user taps on the custom switch, it's calling the incorrect target. It should call:

```
@IBAction func toggleSwitchSection0Tapped(_ sender: UIButton)
```

But instead calls the old target:

```
@IBAction func toggleSwitchTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
```

I can't fathom why this is happening as the tableView is reloading fine, the cells swap places as expected (section 1 to section 0)

My code in cellForRowAtIndex is pretty straight forward with the following target added to the custom switch depending on the section:
cellForRowAtIndex in Section 0:

```
cell.toggleSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.toggleSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ShareListVC.toggleSwitchSection0Tapped), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And cellForRowAtIndex in Section 1:

```
cell1.toggleSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ShareListVC.toggleSwitchTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Interestingly when the tableView list appears and there are cells in section 0 the correct target is called when a user taps the custom switch in section 0.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated....thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Figured Out The Solution**

So after my initial post and re-reading it, I thought that having the same CustomTableViewCell in each section might be causing the issue due to reusing the same cell.

I created a separate CustomTableViewCell for section 0 and section 1 and all is now working as expected!

It's amazing how writing a problem down can make you see things in a different way.